# Conky disappears when using ctrl+super+D

Tags: shortcut-keys, window, conky

When using the desktop shortcut Conky disappears. I also don't want it always in front though. Is there a solution to just display Conky on the desktop, but hide it when every other application has focus? I'm using Ubuntu 13.04.

**EDIT:**

A good solution exists here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1689954

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `own_window_type normal` to `own_window_type override` in your .conkyrc will probably do the trick.

Comment: Thx, worked. Unfortunately the tranparency is gone now.

Comment: Ah no, that was just temporarily. But now conky is always in foreground. But thats a good tip anyways. I just play around with the config a little.

Comment: This might help: http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html

Comment: Here is a good solution described: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1689954

Answer (score 3):

Open the configuration file in your home folder `~/.conkyrc` and change `own_window_type normal` to `own_window_type desktop`

Though some have pointed out that parameters like `override`,`dock` or `panel` might work as well, the parameter `desktop` gives the nicest behaviour in most cases.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I guess that the parameter you are suggesting to be edited is defined in your `.conkyrc`. Then I suggest you to edit your own question to complete it by specifying it please. That way people won't have to read others answers to understand yours ;)

Answer (score 1):

Open Terminal and type : `sudo gedit ~/.conkyrc`

after change .conkyrc file to like this and save it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

but if you still need to relaunch it with a single command, then

```
kill -HUP $(ps aux | grep conky | sed -e '1b' -e '/syslog/!d'  | awk '{print $2}')
```